# Firebase notification onMessage not hitting when chrome tab is open but not active

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have setup firebase messaging service and it works like a charm. Only problem is in `messaging.onMessage` function I have incremented count of notification on my page. Additionally I also have service worker setup that throws chrome notifications in background.

[image: notification bell with counter]

When my tab is **open but not active**, `messaging.onMessage` is not getting hit, but background handler service worker is hitting. So counter on my website is not increasing. When user goes to my website tab back again, it shows old notification count. That is creating bad UX. I am showing notifications list on click of count as like facebook shows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're updating the notification badge count. But, you could retrieve the whole payload in the callback function below:

for background:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {

     console.log(payload.data.badgeCount);

     return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
});
```

for foreground:

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {

     console.log(payload.data.badgeCount);

});
```

Whether the web app is in foreground or background state, get the payload in the onMessage callback and setBackgroundMessageHandler callback, respectively, then update the UI.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am doing same. Problem is we can not access DOM in setBackgroundMessageHandler. I have count in my website. I want to update that count on setBackgroundMessageHandler. We dont have access of document in setBackgroundMessageHandler. Can we do that in any way? As tab is open (not active) count should update. So that when user goes to that tab. He can see updated count

Comment: Indeed, the SW can't access the DOM directly. This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#what_is_a_service_worker) says that you can use the [postMessage](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#what_is_a_service_worker) interface to communicate with other pages, then those pages can manipulate the DOM if needed.

Answer (score 0):

When your website is not in the active tab, Firebase SDK will either show a notification or call the function that you can set using `setBackgroundMessageHandler`. If your payload includes a `notification` field, a notification will be shown. Otherwise, your callback will be called.

I recommend that you don't send a `notification` payload (you can still send it inside the `data` field, and write a background message handler.

See this [Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_background) for more information.

Comment: I have set payload in data field only. My setBackgroundMessageHandler is working properly. But I need to execute my page script on setBackgroundMessageHandler. I want to increase count(notification count in page) in background.

Comment: Firebase SDK uses [Client.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) method to communicate between service worker and window. You can implement something similar. [Here](http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html) is a guide.